# Is my Expression wrong and does it not compile correctly?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

My application I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Decimal'
```

The following code is part of creating an Expression

```
 var conditions = ParseTree<T>(item, itemExpression); 

 if (conditions.CanReduce)
 {
     conditions = conditions.ReduceAndCheck();
 }

 var query = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>>(conditions, itemExpression);//<--  changed from itemExpression to block

 return query;
```

The Query is spitting back the following result:

```
{
   valueBag => (IsMatch(Convert(valueBag.Item["pnt_name"], String), "^") And 
   (IsMatch(Convert(valueBag.Item["pnt_name"], String), "FP") And 
   (Convert(valueBag.Item["pnt_no"], Decimal) == 4)))
}
```

Then when I run `query.Compile();` it returns `{Method = <Internal Error evaluating expression>}`

If the last part of expression is removed (`(Convert(valueBag.Item["pnt_no"], Decimal) == 4)))`) then all is good.

The following code is responsible for creating the expression (based on Jeremy Likness Blog)

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using System.Data;


namespace ExpressionGenerator
{
    public class JsonExpressionParser
    {
        private const string StringStr = "string";

        private readonly string BooleanStr = nameof(Boolean).ToLower();

        private readonly string Number = nameof(Number).ToLower();
        private readonly string In = nameof(In).ToLower();
        private readonly string And = nameof(And).ToLower();
        private readonly string Contains = nameof(Contains).ToLower();

        //Method construction
        private readonly MethodInfo MethodContains = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(
                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains)
                            && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);

        private readonly MethodInfo PerformMyMeth =
            typeof(Regex).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.ToString() == nameof(Regex.IsMatch)
                        && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);


        private delegate Expression Binder(Expression left, Expression right);

        private Expression ParseTree<T>(
            JsonElement condition,
            ParameterExpression parm)
        {
            Expression left = null;
            var gate = condition.GetProperty("Condition").GetString();
            
            JsonElement Rules = condition.GetProperty(nameof(Rules));

            Binder binder = gate == And ? (Binder)Expression.And : Expression.Or;
            Expression bind(Expression left, Expression right) =>
                       left == null ? right : binder(left, right);



            string valueConcatenated = string.Empty;
            foreach (var rule in Rules.EnumerateArray())
            {


                if (rule.TryGetProperty("Condition", out JsonElement check))
                {
                    var right = ParseTree<T>(rule, parm);
                    left = bind(left, right);
                    continue;
                }


                string @Operator = rule.GetProperty(nameof(@Operator)).GetString();     //eg. IN
                string @Type = rule.GetProperty(nameof(@Type)).GetString();               //eg. string
                string @Field = rule.GetProperty(nameof(@Field)).GetString();             //eg. PntName

                JsonElement @Value = rule.GetProperty(nameof(@Value));                    //værdien > Erstae
                valueConcatenated += @Value.ToString();



                
                try
                {

                    var propertyInfo = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetProperty("Item");


                    var arguments = new List<Expression> {
                                        Expression.Constant(@Field)
                                    };


                    var property = Expression.Convert(
                        Expression.MakeIndex(parm, propertyInfo, arguments),
                         (@Type == StringStr || @Type == BooleanStr) ?
                            typeof(string)  : typeof(Decimal)
                        );



                    if (@Operator == In)
                    {

                        var contains = MethodContains.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

                        object val = @Value.EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetString())
                            .ToList();

                        var right = Expression.Call(
                            contains,
                            Expression.Constant(val),
                            property);
                        left = bind(left, right);
                    }
                    else if (@Operator == Contains)
                    {
                        left = null!;

                        object val = valueConcatenated;

                        var toCompare = Expression.Constant(val);

                        var right = Expression.Call(PerformMyMeth, property, toCompare);


                        left = bind(left, right);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object val = (@Type == StringStr || @Type == BooleanStr) ?
                            (object)@Value.GetString() : @Value.GetDecimal();
                        var toCompare = Expression.Constant(val);
                        var right = Expression.Equal(property, toCompare);
                        left = bind(left, right);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw new Exception();

                }



            }
            return left;
        }

        public Expression<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>> ParseExpressionOf<T>(JsonElement doc)
        {
            var itemExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>), "valueBag");
      
                    var conditions = ParseTree<T>(doc, itemExpression); 

                    if (conditions.CanReduce)
                    {
                        conditions = conditions.ReduceAndCheck();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Conditions: " + conditions.ToString());

                    var query = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>>(conditions, itemExpression);

                    return query;

        }

        public Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> ParsePredicateOf<T>(JsonElement doc)
        {
            var query = ParseExpressionOf<T>(doc);
            try
            {
                return query.Compile();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON dokument:

```
{
  "condition": "and",
  "Name": null,
  "Paths": [
    {
      "ObjectClassId": null,
      "Properties": null,
      "Lvl": 0,
      "Condition": "and",
      "Id": null,
      "Name": "",
      "ParentId": null,
      "TwinInfo": null,
      "DataRules": null,
      "TwinObject": null,
      "TwinRelationships": null,
      "Children": [
        {
          "ObjectClassId": null,
          "Properties": null,
          "Lvl": 0,
          "Condition": "and",
          "Id": "Pumpestationer",
          "Name": "",
          "ParentId": "Root",
          "TwinInfo": null,
          "Rules": [
            {
              "Condition": "and",
              "Rules": [
                {
                  "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                  "Label": "pnt_name",
                  "Field": "pnt_name",
                  "Type": "string",
                  "Value": "^",
                  "Operator": "contains"

                },
                {
                  "Condition": "and",
                  "Rules": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                      "Label": "pnt_name",
                      "Field": "pnt_name",
                      "Type": "string",
                      "Value": "FP",
                      "Operator": "contains"

                    },
                    {
                      "Condition": "and",
                      "Rules": [
                        {
                          "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                          "Label": "descr",
                          "Field": "descr",
                          "Type": "string",
                          "Value": "Sidste",
                          "Operator": "contains"

                        }
                      ]

                    }
                  ]

                }
              ],
              "DataRules": null,
              "Lvl": 0,
              "ObjectClassId": null
            }
          ],
          "TwinObject": null,
          "TwinRelationships": null,
          "Children": [
            {
              "ObjectClassId": null,
              "Properties": null,
              "Lvl": 0,
              "Condition": "and",
              "Id": "PST",
              "Name": "",
              "ParentId": "Pumpestationer",
              "TwinInfo": null,
              "Rules": [
                {
                  "Condition": "and",
                  "Rules": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                      "Label": "pnt_name",
                      "Field": "pnt_name",
                      "Type": "string",
                      "Value": "Timetæller",
                      "Operator": "contains"

                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "TwinObject": null,
              "TwinRelationships": null,
              "Children": [
                {
                  "ObjectClassId": null,
                  "Properties": null,
                  "Lvl": 0,
                  "Condition": "and",
                  "Id": "PST",
                  "Name": "",
                  "ParentId": "Pumpestationer",
                  "TwinInfo": null,
                  "DataRules": [
                    {
                      "Condition": "and",
                      "Rules": [
                        {
                          "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                          "Label": "pnt_name",
                          "Field": "pnt_name",
                          "Type": "string",
                          "Value": "STOP",
                          "Operator": "contains"

                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "TwinObject": null,
                  "TwinRelationships": null,

                  "SourceParentExpression": null,
                  "SourceExpression": null,
                  "RelationshipName": null
                }
              ],
              "SourceParentExpression": null,
              "SourceExpression": null,
              "RelationshipName": null
            }
          ],
          "SourceParentExpression": null,
          "SourceExpression": null,
          "RelationshipName": null
        },
        {
          "ObjectClassId": null,
          "Properties": null,
          "Lvl": 0,
          "Condition": "and",
          "Id": "Pumpestationer",
          "Name": "",
          "ParentId": "Root",
          "TwinInfo": null,
          "Rules": [
            {
              "Condition": "and",
              "Rules": [
                {
                  "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                  "Label": "descr",
                  "Field": "descr",
                  "Type": "string",
                  "Value": "Timetæller",
                  "Operator": "contains"

                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "TwinObject": null,
          "TwinRelationships": null,
          "Children": [
            {
              "ObjectClassId": null,
              "Properties": null,
              "Lvl": 0,
              "Condition": "and",
              "Id": "PST",
              "Name": "",
              "ParentId": "Pumpestationer",
              "TwinInfo": null,
              "Rules": [
                {
                  "Condition": "and",
                  "Rules": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Rule_Contains_Carrot",
                      "Label": "descr",
                      "Field": "descr",
                      "Type": "string",
                      "Value": "Timetæller",
                      "Operator": "contains"

                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "TwinObject": null,
              "TwinRelationships": null,
              "Children": [
              ],
              "SourceParentExpression": null,
              "SourceExpression": null,
              "RelationshipName": null
            }
          ],
          "SourceParentExpression": null,
          "SourceExpression": null,
          "RelationshipName": null
        }
      ],
      "SourceParentExpression": null,
      "SourceExpression": null,
      "RelationshipName": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] for us to play with?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama thanks for reply. I just added the code that is responsible for creating the expression

Comment: @KN please also add the json input you are tyring to convert into an expression.

Comment: @PeterE thanks, just updated the post with json data

Comment: @KN unfortunatly the json you provided does neither conform to the structure expected by the expression parser (although some subsections seem to fit) nor does it seem to contain the section that causes your problem (there is no pnt_no in it). Please provide a complete and executable sample. Perhaps as a .NET Fiddle like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qNMXZ

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? For most Json-processing I would use System.Text.Json, either to just let it serialize/deserialize objects, or manually processing the DOM. Expression tend to make things more complicated, so are you *sure* that is the best approach for whatever it is you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

`Expression.Convert` is the equivalent of a cast. You are trying to do `((Decimal)"5.50")` which will fail because there is no cast from `string` to `Decimal`.

Instead you need to generate the code to do `Decimal.Parse("5.50")` to convert the value.